# Adding int with int[]

Tags: java

```
 int sum = 0;   

      for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)      
      {
            sum = sum + counts[i];  //doesnt work says + bad operator  first type int second type int[]

      } 
      return sum;
```

I thought this would work but it doesn't what can i do to make it work?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[][] counts =
     {
        { 1, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 0 }
     };
  int sum = ArrayUtil.rowSum(counts, 5);
  System.out.println(sum);
  System.out.println("Expected: 2");

  int[][] magicSquare = {
     { 16, 3, 2, 13 },
     { 5, 10, 11, 8 },
     { 9, 6, 7, 12 },
     { 4, 15, 14, 1 },
  };

  for (int row = 0; row <= 3; row++)
  {
     System.out.println(ArrayUtil.rowSum(magicSquare, row));
     System.out.println("Expected: 34");
  }
}
  public static int rowSum(int[][] counts, int row) 
  {   
      int sum = 0;   

      for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)      
      {
            sum = sum + counts[i];    

      } 
      return sum;
  }
```

added the full code that i have. thanks for anyhelp in advance. 
is it not working because the counts[i] is part of a 2d array?

Comment: I guess `counts` it's an array of int's, right?

Comment: What doesn't work? What were you inputs and output and how did the output differ from what you expected? Or did something not compile?

Comment: What is not working?  The code snippet looks fine (at least what you have shown us).

Comment: Please add more details on what doesn't work

Comment: updated it with a comment

Comment: On a side note, you should be incrementing by using `+=` e.g. `sum += counts[i];`

Comment: `counts` appears to be a 2D `int` array.  Show us the full code.

Comment: @Michael "should" is a little strong for this context.

Comment: you  are dealing with 2d arrays what is any good reason to write 1d array sum for 2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to sum a single row of a 2D array, your method should look like this:

```
public static int rowSum(int[][] counts, int row) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int count : counts[row]) {
        sum += count;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`counts` is a multidimensional array, so you'll need to iterate the values contained within the inner array(s) to get your `sum`. Using [`for-each` loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) that might look something like,

```
int sum = 0;
for (int[] array : counts) {  // <-- for each array in counts
    for (int value : array) { // <-- for each value in the array
        sum += value;         // <-- add the value to the sum
    }
}
```

Applying the same loop structure to `rowSum`, we might get

```
public static int rowSum(int[][] counts, int row) {   
    int sum = 0;   
    for (int value : counts[row]) {
        sum += value;
    } 
    return sum;
}
```

**or** using a Java 8+ [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) like

```
public static int rowSum(int[][] counts, int row) {
    return IntStream.of(counts[row]).sum();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`counts` is a 2D array of `int` (i.e. `int[][]`) You cannot add `int[]` to an `int`.

If you want to sum the value of `counts`, consider the following code:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < counts[i].length; j++) {
        sum += counts[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this with recursion as everyone posted their own answer so i did this recursive way.

```
int rowSum(int a[][], int row, int col) {    
    if (row == a.length-1)
        return a[row][col];    
    if(col == a[row].length-1)
        return a[row][col]+rowSum(a,row+1,0);    
    return a[row][col]+rowSum(a,row,col+1);
}
```

Hope you found my answer helpful.